# NodeJs : Multiple file upload with Multer

Tags: node.js, forms

I have the following code :

```
import { Router } from 'express';
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'})

router.post('/file/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
    return res.status(200).json({
        'name' : 'here'
    });
});

export default router;
```

I am uploading a file with `postman`.

Request Type : `POST`

Header : `Content-Type : multipart/form-data`

Body : `file : path/filename.jpg`

[Mutler package link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

**The response comes ok, But the file does't upload to the directory specified above.**

Answer (score 0):

> The response comes ok, But the file does't upload to the directory specified above.

This is because in route handler you return `res.status(200)` for every case. you are not checking for errors in upload.
To check for errors in upload you can do something like this:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'}).single('file');

router.post('/file/upload', function (req, res, next) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            'name' : 'done'
        });
        console.log(req);
    });
});
```

The error you will get is `Error: Multipart: Boundary not found`. This is because you have set `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` in header but it is missing boundary which  is used to separate the "multiple parts" of the multipart request body.
Remove content-type from the header, it is automatically set when you send the request.